# Complete thread dumps in Karaf

Tags: apache-karaf

When I use `dev:create-dump`, the thread stacks in the dump are incomplete. Is it possible to configure Karaf to:

1. dump full stacks?
2. detect deadlocks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dev:create-dump` : Creates an archive with info

What you actually need is:

`dev:dump-create`

This will create a file in $KARAF_HOME/

The file name in my case is like 2015-04-13_140239.zip

http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/developers-guide/developer-commands.html

The zip file contains all what you require, and more than that:

```
bundles.txt
environment.txt
features.txt
memory.txt
threads.txt
```